# not getting expected result - array loop

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

ok, so this is in ActionScript 3, my problem is here:

```
var numCols:uint = 7;
numRows:uint = 7;

row = 1;
column = 3;

total = row+column-1    
for(i = 0; i < numRows; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < numCols; j++){
        if(j < column){
            array[i][j]=total--
        }else{
            array[i][j]=total++                     
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting this result in array:

```
3,2,1,2,3,4....
```

However I get this:

```
3,2,1,0,1,2,3,4...
```

Comment: Unless you put the value of the 2-dimensional array, it's difficult to say where the problem is.

Comment: do you want to know the values before I try to run this code?

Comment: Yes, otherwise how should I know what the code fragment is supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

Your condition

```
if (j < column)
```

evaluates to `true` three times.

> ```
> 1. column = 3, j = 0, total = 3, total becomes 2
> 2. column = 3, j = 1, total = 2, total becomes 1
> 3. column = 3, j = 2, total = 1, total becomes 0
> ```

the fourth time, the `else` clause gets executed but by this time, **your `total` has dropped to 0.**

> ```
> 4. column = 3, j = 3, total = 0, total becomes 1.
> ```

#### Possible solution

I don't know your use case but changing

```
array[i][j]=total++
```

to

```
array[i][j]=++total
```

could be all it takes.